# Avoiding a fuzzy display when using 2 monitors through a Dell WD15 dock

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, displayport

At work, I use my laptop (a reasonably new Dell Latitude 5490 with Windows 10) connected to a Dell WD15 dock.  With the laptop screen closed, this drives a single Samsung S23C650 monitor at 1920 x 1080 pixels, through the dock's Mini DisplayPort.  The display is nice and clear enough to do my work.

I have now acquired another S23C650 monitor and I want to connect it through the dock to achieve an extended display of 2 x (1920 x 1080 pixels).  The monitors have VGA, DVI-D and DisplayPort sockets - no HDMI.

I've tried an analogue VGA cable, but the display on the second screen is noticeably 'fuzzier'.  So, I'm wondering how best to connect the 2 monitors through the dock:

1. I could get a VGA to DVI-D connector, but would that make it less 'fuzzy'?  Or how about a VGA to DisplayPort adaptor, if such a thing was possible?
2. Several forums on the internet suggest a HDMI to DisplayPort adaptor might work, but others say there is no such thing and instead I would have to go to via a DVI adaptor anyway.  So I could go HDMI to DVI-D to DisplayPort.  But if I'm going to do that, why not stop at the HDMI to DVI-D.  Would any of these solutions make the second screen less 'fuzzy'?
3. Amazon also sells a number of DisplayPort splitters, where 1 mini-DP is split into two through a little box.  But these are quite expensive compared to various cables (typically £50+) and I am unsure whether they would allow the extend display I want.

**Update:** I acquired a HDMI to DVI-D cable.  While the display was less fuzzy, it introduced strange artefacts to the text displayed on both monitors - every few millimetres the verticals of letters seemed to be double-width.  In effect, the display on both monitors was worse than the slight fuzziness of one monitor using the analogue VGA connection.  I got the impression that it would start to induce headaches after some hours, so I've gone back to using the VGA cable for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

DVI-D is compatible with HDMI in [many cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) and should not require any kind of signal conversion for the use you describe. "So just stop there."

> "To promote interoperability between DVI-D and HDMI devices, HDMI
>   source components and displays support DVI-D signalling. For example,
>   an HDMI display can be driven by a DVI-D source because HDMI and DVI-D
>   both define an overlapping minimum set of supported resolutions and
>   frame buffer formats."

There are potential limitations like hdmi copy protection handshaking, bandwidth (1920x should be fine), etc. but a simple hdmi-to-dvi-d adapter should work. These are often bundled with graphic cards.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that anything involving an analog VGA link is going to be fuzzy relative to a pure digital connection.